# Problems with the Minecraft Launcher

Tags: launcher, minecraft, versions

Each time I am trying to run a version of Minecraft below 1.13, the game crashes, and it says that they are sorry for inconvinience and if you would like to report the problem. I tried restarting my computer and reinstalling the minecraft launcher but none of it work. Can somebody please help me.